# Product of two cyclic subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with $x, y \in G$. Then is true that $\langle x \rangle \langle y \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle$ always holds?

Since $x, \,y \in \langle x \rangle \langle y \rangle$, we have by definition $\langle x, y \rangle \subseteq \langle x \rangle \langle y \rangle$. Now let $z \in \langle x \rangle \langle y \rangle$. Then $z = x^ny^m$ for some $n, m \in \mathbb{Z}$. We must have that $z \in \langle \langle x \rangle, \langle y \rangle \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle$. I'm not sure about the last statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your argument is that $\langle x \rangle \langle y \rangle $ is not always a subgroup.

In particular, it may happen (and is even probable) that $yx \notin \langle x \rangle \langle y \rangle $.

In fact,  $HK$ is a subgroup if and only if $HK = KH$.

Comment: Ahh yes I completely forgot about that. So if I impose that condition, would my statement hold?

Comment: Would it be sufficient for $x$ and $y$ commuting i.e would my statement hold if $xy=yx$?

Comment: @RMaharaj, yes and yes.